# Field equipped for research purpose Vs Field use for research purposes

Tags: sentence-construction

> Professional astronomers,
> unlike their amateur counterparts, have no particular interest in the aesthetic quality
> of their photographs. What matters to them is the contribution their images can make to research,
> and to the **use/collection** of data scientists in their field **equipped/use** for research purposes.

Can anyone guide me on what should be the correct answer and why?

**My approach**

For 1st I think as per context research can be used for data scientist hence **use** make sense to me

For 2nd equipped means provide/supply/provision hence I think since the research papers are provided for research paper hence **equipped** make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first choice, between use and collection, should be collection:
"collection of data".

The second choice, between equipped and use, should be use.
"... data scientists in their field use for research "

The phrase "in their field" is a modifier of "scientists"; it is the scientists who **use** the data.

I think the sentence as a whole is really badly constructed, though. It would make more sense like this:

> What matters to them is the collection of data that scientists can use for research purposes.

Comment: You don't say why you prefer "collection" to "use" in the first option. It seems to me that the writer is talking about how useful (or not) the information can be, and so "collection" (whether as a verb or a noun) is not as relevant, although not wrong.

Comment: @DavidSiegel The problem with "use" is the resulting phrase: "the USE of data [that] scientists USE for research..."  What makes sense is "the collection of data that scientists use".

Answer (score 1):

> ... scientists in their field equipped for research purposes.

This would mean those scientists who have the proper instruments, or the proper training for such research. That doesn't fit the meaning of the overall sentence.  Thus, of the alternatives give I would write:

> What matters to them is the contribution their images can make to research, and to the use of data scientists in their field use for research purposes.

However, the double use of "use" feels awkward here, and I would rewrite this to avoid that and to clarify the meaning, something like:

> What matters to them is the contribution their images can make to research, and how useful the images are to scientists in their field for research.

or

> What matters to them is the contribution their images can make to research, and the quality of data the images will provide to scientists doing research in their field.

And in all these cases the second clause is essentially redundant, so it might be better to simply write:

> What matters to them is the contribution their images can make to research.

and stop right there.